# Need to show $x_1=x_2=x_3=\ldots=x_n=\phi$ for the given sequence of $n$ positive positive numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

The question states:

> There are $n$ positive numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$, where $n \geq 3$, satisfy
>   $$
> x_1=1+\frac{1}{x_2},\ x_2 = 1+\frac{1}{x_3},\ \cdots, \ x_{n-1}=1+\frac{1}{x_n}
> $$
>   and also,
>   $$
> x_n=1+\frac{1}{x_1}
> $$
>   Show that
>
> 1. $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3 \cdots x_n > 1$
> 2. $x_1 - x_2 = -\frac{x_2-x_3}{x_2x_3}$
> 3. $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n$
>
> Hence find the value of $x_1$

I could do $(1)$ and $(2)$ quite easily. Here's how:

1. Plugging in
   $$
   x_1=1+\frac{1}{x_2},\ x_2 = 1+\frac{1}{x_3},\ \cdots, \ x_{n-1}=1+\frac{1}{x_n}
   $$
   and
   $$
   x_n=1+\frac{1}{x_1}
   $$

in $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3 \cdots x_n$, we get
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x_1}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{x_3}\right)\cdots \left(1+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)\\
=1+k>1
$$
where $k$ is a positive number.

2. Just by substituting the expressions for $x_1$ and $x_2$, we get
   $$
   x_1-x_2=1+\frac{1}{x_2}-1-\frac{1}{x_3}=\frac{1}{x_2}-\frac{1}{x_3}\\
   =-\frac{x_2-x_3}{x_2x_3}
   $$

Now I've tried for a day but I couldn't find a way to prove that they're all equal. A nudge in the proper direction would be appreciated.

---

### Edit

Following [copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27978/copper-hat)'s [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127005/need-to-show-x-1-x-2-x-3-ldots-x-n-for-the-given-sequence-of-n-positive-pos?noredirect=1#comment4374148_2127005), I decided to analyse the function $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}$. Here's what I did:

$$
f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x} \\
(f \circ f)(x)=f^2(x)=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\\
\vdots\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\underbrace{f \circ f \cdots f}_{n \text{ times}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}f^n(x)=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\ddots}}=\phi
$$

Therefore, intuitively it's easy to see that all the terms are $\phi$. But how do I prove this rigorously? Or *how* should I write it to prove the third claim? Basically this post is about seeking guidance in mastering Mathematical lingo now.

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1+ {1 \over x}$ and examine how $f(f(...f(x)...))$ behaves and look for fixed points. For $x \ge 1$, $f$ is bounded and monotonic.

Comment: @copper.hat It seems to be behaving sort of like $f^n(x)=\frac{F_n x+F_{n-1}}{F_{n-1}x+F_{n-2}}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: @copper.hat Am I correct?

Comment: @Astrobleme Not too surprising, since if $x_1=x_2$ then it's the root of $x^2-x-1=0$ i.e. the golden ratio.

Comment: For each $i$ we have $|x_i-x_{i+1}|=|(x_{i+1}-x_{i+2})/(x_ix_{i+1})|\leq|x_{i+1}-x_{i+2}|$, because $x_j>1$ for each $j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $(2)$ repeatedly you get
$$
\lvert  x_1 - x_2 \rvert  = \frac{\lvert x_2-x_3\rvert }{x_2x_3} = 
  \frac{\lvert x_3-x_4\rvert }{x_2x_3^2x_4} = \ldots =
  \frac{\lvert x_{n}-x_1 \rvert }{x_2x_3^2x_4^2\cdots x_{n-1}^2x_n^2x_1} \\ =
 \frac{\lvert x_1-x_2 \rvert }{x_2x_3^2x_4^2\cdots x_{n-1}^2x_n^2x_1^2 x_2} = 
 \frac{\lvert x_1-x_2 \rvert }{(x_1\cdots x_n)^2}
$$
In $(1)$ you have shown that the denominator is strictly greater
than one, therefore $x_1 - x_2 = 0$ must hold, and consequently,
all $x_i$ are equal.